# How can I set up a database (SQL?) for literary annotations?

Tags: sql

I'm a literature student and I'd like to be able to annotate literary texts (originally stored in HTML or as text files) on a word-by-word or line-by-line basis. I hear databases like mySQL or SQLite would be good ways to do this sort of thing, but I don't really know where to start.

I'm comfortable with the linux command-line, and have done some HTML/CSS work in the past, so I feel unintimidated by databases and things...I just don't know what to start doing.

Comment: Consider a personal wiki instead of a database (which might be overkill for your needs).

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of MySQL tutorials on the web, e.g. [this one](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/).

Once you learn the basics of SQL, if you want to make a database for annotating lines, you could read each line of a text file separately into a table called `LINES_OF_TEXT` using the [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command in MySQL.  You can then have another table called `ANNOTATIONS` that refers to entries in the `LINES_OF_TEXT` table; that way you can have multiple annotations for each line of text.  E.g.:

```
LINES_OF_TEXT_TABLE
ID    | line
---------------------------------    
1     | This is a line, 
2     | and another one follows.


ANNOTATIONS_TABLE
lines_of_text_ID | annotation
-----------------------------------------------
1                | has a comma
1                | starts with a capital letter
2                | ends with a period
2                | dependent clause
1                | passive voice
```

You can relate the tables to each other using [JOIN](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php) queries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure a SQL database is your best solution here. They're not really meant as end-user tools more as back-end storage for applications.

You might be better off with just a spreadsheet ... OR ... why not come up with your own annotation scheme, e.g. `<!-- MYNOTE: This is a note !-->`, and add it to the file directly. Then using an indexed search program (e.g. lucene) you'd be able to find your annotations quickly.